# Electron notification click not working when notification is "disappear"

Tags: notifications, electron

I have Windows 10 and app in Electron: 28.2.3. This is my code for display system notification:

```js
export const showSystemNotification = (
  notificationData: NotificationCustomOptions,
) => {
  const icon = nativeImage.createFromPath(join(PUBLIC, 'icon.ico'))
  const notification = new Notification({
    ...notificationData,
    icon,
  })

  notification.on('click', async () => {
    console.log('click!')
    if (notificationData.url) await openURL(notificationData.url)
  })

  notification.show()
}
```

When the notification first appears, clicking it has the desired effect, but when notification is going to "Action Center" (I don't know what is the name of the place to which the notification disappears is), then clicking the notification has no effect.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolve. This [answer](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/29461#issuecomment-1191037511) helped me.
This line resolve my problem:

```
<toast launch="my_app_name://" activationType="protocol">
```

This is my code for display notification in Windows system:

```
const iconPath = join(PUBLIC, "icon.ico");

const notification = new Notification({
  toastXml: `<toast launch="my_app_name://" activationType="protocol">
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
        <text id="1">${notificationData.title}</text>
        <text id="2">${notificationData.body}</text>
        <image src="${iconPath}" alt="Logo" placement="appLogoOverride" />
        </binding>
    </visual>
    </toast>`,
});

notification.on("click", () => {
  console.log('Click!')
});

notification.show();
```

Here is more information about [Toast schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/tiles/toastschema/schema-root).